# Mass acknowledging alert in NAGIOS

Tags: nagios

Good evening to all!

I was wondering around to find solution of mass acknowledging the alerts all at once for 500+ service notification in Nagios. After a long hardship, I came across building below script own. Please help in analyzing pros and cons or if another best alternative available to it.

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in $(cat list.txt)
do
    domainname=$name
    now=`date +%s`
    command="/var/spool/nagios/cmd/nagios.cmd"
    service=blacklist-check

    #The show begins
    /usr/bin/printf "[%lu] ACKNOWLEDGE_SVC_PROBLEM;$domainname;$service;2;1;1;mail_it;Should be de-listed in 1 week till 18 Nov, 2021.\n" $now >> $command
    echo "$name ACKNOWLEDGED! "

done
echo "ALL COMPLETED"
```

*Early reply will be appreciable.*

Thanking You

Regards,
Nishi

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the Nagios version you are using and as well is it opensource or Nagios X1.

Regards,
Kamal

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Your answer currently does not seem to provide a workable solution to the question and might be more appropriate as a comment. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) and consider revising or deleting your current answer. And don't forget to take the [site tour](http://serverfault.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

This script will work, as it is basically the same as clicking through all the services on a web interface, acknowledging them one by one.

However, there is on thing you should consider. The command file (`nagios.cmd`) is a named pipe, and as such, has a limited buffer in which commands can be stored. Depending on how many commands you want to issue at one time, you might want to set `external_command_buffer_slots` and / or `command_check_interval` appropriately (see [Nagios configuration docs](https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/configmain.html#check_external_commands) for more info).